# Java 11 HTTP Client custom executor thread pool size

Tags: java, java-11

When providing a custom Executor to the Java 11 HTTP client, it seems that there is a minimum number of threads that the http client requires in order to operate, but this restriction appears not to be documented, or enforced.

For example, the following code just hangs, or rather the request never completes:

```
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 2, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<>());
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().executor(executor).build();

    URI url = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://www.google.com").build();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(url)
            .GET()
            .build();

    httpClient
            .sendAsync(request, BodyHandlers.ofString())
            .thenAccept(response->{
                System.out.println(response.body());
            });
```

If I provide 3 threads, it completes successfully.

I'm trying to provide a restricted threadpool to the client, since I don't want it using an unlimited number of threads. But I've no idea what the requirements on the thread pool are in order to make the client still operate correctly. In this example 3 is enough, but I've no idea whether other examples would require more.

I can't find any documentation anywhere that would seem to explain this, and the code doesn't seem to enforce any restrictions, meaning it appears very easy to create an http client that won't successfully complete any requests.

I've seen various examples that create custom thread pools that specify 5, 6 threads, but with no justification or explanation of the apparent dangers of limiting the thread pool size.

I don't understand enough of the inner working of completable futures, or enough of the workings of the http client itself to reason about how many threads it might need for any given task, but then neither should I.

Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: Interestingly, using a ForkJoinPool with parallelism of 1 does work.

Comment: Running under the debugger with the ThreadPoolExecutor of unlimited threads, the example has the effect of creating 3 worker threads, suggesting that's the number that example needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't do any blocking operations in your callbacks/dependent actions/subscribers/publishers a single thread should be enough - barring bugs in the HttpClient implementation. However using a single thread means that if you are performing concurrent requests then the work will necessarily be serialized at some point.